# RecyclerView adapter show only first item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I know that this question has been asked many times, but the answers doesn't work for me. I am trying to use Horizontal placement. Here is my code:

```
public class CalendarDaysAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CalendarDaysAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<String> list;

    public CalendarDaysAdapter(ArrayList<String> list)
    {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.fragment_calendar_days_item, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        String day = list.get(position);
        holder.daystxt.setText(day);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }


    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView daystxt;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            daystxt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.daystxt);
        }
    }

}
```

fragment_calendar_days_item **xml**:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/daystxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="MON"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

I tried every combination of wrap_content - match_parent, also on the RecyclerView xml in parent Activity, but only the first item is showing. I have used breakpoints to see if the data of the list are there, and they are.

So what I am missing ?

Comment: check if  you can see other items after scrolling

Comment: show the adapter setting code with the list item you creating

Comment: add pointer on arraylist and check what is size of list. You code is looking fine. just debug and check.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Change your **`fragment_calendar_days_item`** height and width to **`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`** and **`android:layout_width="wrap_content"`**

it will solve your issue

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/daystxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="MON"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was layout_width="wrap_content" because I am using Horizontal placement. Change it so I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this for your

fragment_calendar_days_item xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/daystxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="MON"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is show that "n" elements and the rest must be scrollable.

The solution of setting the hard value is not the best. it's not generic. I think that my solution will fit very well in any case. ;-)

For that I propose you a solution

## First determine and create a MAX_ITEMS variable

## Kotlin

```
recycler.addOnLayoutChangeListener { v, left, top, right, bottom, oldLeft, oldTop, oldRight, oldBottom ->
    if (recycler.layoutManager.itemCount > maxItemVisible) {
        val height = (0 until maxItemVisible).sumBy { recycler.layoutManager.findViewByPosition(it).height }
        recycler.layoutParams = LayoutParams(recycler.width, height)
    }
}
```

## Java

```
mRecycler.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
        if (mRecycler.getLayoutManager().getItemCount() > maxItemVisible) {
            int height = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < maxItemVisible; i++){
                height += mRecycler.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(i).getHeight()
            }
            mRecycler.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(mRecycler.getWidth(), height));
        }
    }
});
```

Hoping to have answered your need

Comment: Then it is quite possible to create a class Utils, or Extension Kotlin to avoid duplicating the code if the use case is multiple